# edit html files without having to ftp everytime?

Tags: html, wysiwyg

is there a way to edit html files through a web browser instead of ftp'ing all the time? I'll limit the editing to certain people with a simple php check on login usernames. I want certain people to edit without the ftp info? Plus, it's just html text file. There is no php code and the text isn't stored in a mysql database where a CMS can help out.

I think WYSIWYG editor is close to what I'm doing? I've tried TinyMCE, but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A platform change to a CMS (Content Management System) is probably the best decision for increased efficiency, usability, and security. My favorite CMS is Wordpress.

If this is not feasible, I would check out something like net2ftp, a web-based FTP client aimed at in-browser website management. Also, web hosting providers offer control panels like cPanel that allow for quick editing of files.

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of a database you would need to use the WYSISYG like you said (or just a plain old text box) and then use server-side(php, asp) code to re-create the file.

I would recommend the use of a database and CMS though.

Comment: Do you have a tutorial/ video tutorial on how do the first option you said? WYSIWYG editor + php. Not sure how to start. Thanks

Comment: I haven't done anything with PHP in so long that I can't think of anything off the top of my head.  Any examples I gave would be in C# or VB.  It looks like Michael Durrant might have the answer you are looking for though.